# Definition of uniformity in different contexts

Tags: terminology, definition, uniform-continuity

My question is rather a semantic one.

I am wondering what *uniformity* in different contexts in general means. I know what the definition of uniform continuity is. Has uniformity in general something to do with this notion (i.e., $\delta$-$\varepsilon$-criterion)?

For example, in a paper I read that the inequality on $x \in (0,1]$
$$
 h(x) \leq C x^{-2} 
$$
means that $h(x)$ blows up *uniformly* (where $C \in \mathbb{R}$ is constant). What does uniformity mean here? The function $x^{-2}$ on the r.h.s. is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$. Or it has something to do with the constant $C$ on the r.h.s. since $C$ remains constant, independent of $x \in (0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

"Uniform" usually means roughly "the same everywhere". In the case of uniform continuity, given some $\epsilon$, the same $\delta$ works everywhere (or, at least, there *is some $\delta$* that works everywhere). It's the continuity that says $\epsilon$-$\delta$ is involved, not the uniformity.

Similarly, a (usually infinite) collection of sequences (including sequences of real functions) is said to converge uniformly to some limit if for any $\epsilon$, you can find an $N$ that works for all sequences simultaneously.

As another example, uniform probability means any possible outcome is equally probable. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: OK, I knew what uniform convergence means. What about the example I've given?

Comment: According to what you say, I think, my second guess would be correct. That is, the constant $C$ is the same as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Astrolabe I am not actually sure about that specific use.